# ВКонтакте - с каким предлогом употреблять?

Tags: предлоги, названия

Где? В "ВКонтакте" или во "ВКонтакте"? Объясните, пожалуйста, чем обоснован выбор предлога, если не используется родовое слово "соцсеть".

Comment: Я бы ни с каким предлогом не употребляла: он уже есть, пусть даже как часть названия.

Comment: На каком правиле базируется ваше мнение?

Comment: А почему непременно на правиле должно базироваться мнение? "Базируемся" на редакторском опыте.

Comment: ВКонтакте - в - часть названия, соцсеть называется не Контакт, название не меняет окончания, мы не можем подставить вместо в другой предлог и поставить слово в другой падеж. Поправьте, если я ошибаюсь. Очень хочу разобраться.

Comment: Как вы скажете "он вошел "ВКонтакт"?  По аналогии с "он вошел в "Фейсбук".

Comment: Да, я не допускаю громоздкости "во ВКонтакте"; легче застрелиться, чем этим осквернить уста. )))  Я бы использовала винительный и предложный падеж без предлога "в(о)" и, соответственно, склоняя нищасный ВКонтакт. С другими предлогами и падежами - дело иное: для "ВКонтакте", без "ВКонтакте"...

Comment: Спасибо за мнение!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Во "В контакте"** (с предлогом "в" не произнести сочетание согласных на стыке слов*); при формальной ссылке на это название в документе: **во "ВКонтакте"**.  Название юридически закреплено с нарушением правил русской орфографии (как и напр. *МегаФон*): заглавные буквы в середине слов, как и слияние существительного с предлогом, не допускаются. За этим стоит только подражание написанию некоторых имён и названий в английском.

Помимо фонетических факторов, на это могут влиять и факторы лексические, связанные, в частности, с устойчивостью фразеологизмов:
http://russkayarech.ru/files/issues/2008/5/12-zotova.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Не бейте меня, пожалуйста, за ответ, я только хочу сказать, как сам говорю, нисколько не навязывая это никому. ;)

Я в уме упрощаю "ВКонтакте" до "контакта" и говорю и пишу "в контакте" раздельно с "в" именно в качестве предлога. "Контакт" на письме можно поставить в кавычки, смотря где это пишешь (честно сказать, я помню, что так говорю, но писать так редко доводится). Например: "Вчера я зашёл в "контакт" и увидел несколько новых сообщений".

Как говорить, *"В лесах"* или *во "В лесах"*, действительно непростой вопрос. Можно, конечно, сказать "Сегодня попался во "В лесах" интересный диалог...", но звучит не очень-то хорошо. Мне кажется, что я интуитивно в таком случае скажу по-другому, чтобы избежать столкновения предлогов: "Сегодня читал "В лесах", и мне там очень понравился один диалог между..."

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
***Поддержите нас в Фейсбуке и во ВКонтакте, пожалуйста!***

[В Контакте, в ВКонтакте, во ВКонтакте - как правильно? - Говорим и
пишем правильно](http://pishu-pravilno.livejournal.com/4418394.html?thread=84569690)

> Я не знаю, как точно разделить понятия «слово» и «словосочетание». Мне
>   кажется, что это сложнее, чем кажется. Я избегаю построений,
>   основанных на различии этих понятий.
>
> Где найти определение падежа, я тоже не знаю. По разным источникам, в
>   русском языке их от 6 до 12, я теряюсь в догадках, кому верить. Я
>   только интуитивно понимаю, что «вконтакте» не только звучит похоже на
>   «в лесу», «в поле» или даже «в одной маленькой, но гордой стране», но
>   и устроено так же. Кажется, это общее устройство обычно называют
>   предложным падежом, иногда местным (локативом) или еще как-то.
>   Насколько я понимаю, вы придерживаетесь другого мнения, именно — что
>   это именительный падеж несклоняемого существительного. Я не понимаю,
>   почему, и не могу согласиться с этим. Есть какие-то доводы в пользу
>   такой точки зрения?
>
> Почему слово в косвенном падеже с предлогом не может быть названием
>   какого-нибудь объекта? Может. Есть, например, романы
>   Мельникова-Печерского «В лесах» и «На горах». Есть повесть Горького «В
>   людях». Я вчера закончил читать «В лесах» и взялся за «На горах», а «В
>   людях» меня пугает, не хочу начинать. По-моему, «Вконтакте» устроено
>   точно так же.
>
> Если это так, то есть два вопроса.
>
> Первый: можно ли говорить «я нашел во "В лесах" интересный пассаж»?
>   (По-моему, однозначно нельзя). Второй: можно ли говорить «я нашел "В
>   лесах" интересный пассаж»? (У меня нет четкого мнения по этому
>   вопросу; мне лично слух не режет).
>
> ---
>
> Правильно, потому что для синтаксиса это неважно. Есть А (Москва,
>   Вконтакте, лес), из которого нужно получить форму "в(о) А" (в чём?):
>   в(о) Москве, в(о) Вконтакте, в(о) лесу.
>
> Я не придерживаюсь иного мнения, сайт называется "Вконтакте" (это его
>   имя и никакое иное). Представьте, что ребёнка назвали Умаши (потому
>   что он родился у Маши), Вы и там будете иной именительному падеж
>   видеть?
>
> Отличный пример: "Я вчера закончил читать «В лесах» и взялся за «На
>   горах», а «В людях» меня пугает, не хочу начинать". "за «На горах»"
>   (остальные названия употребляются беспредложно - прямое дополнение и
>   подлежащее) - здесь Вас не смущает наличие двух предлогов, так как
>   второй, чисто интуитивно, не совсем предлог (а рационально - совсем не
>   предлог).
>
> В одной из альтернатив Вашего вопроса есть фраза "однозначно нельзя",
>   которая ничем не аргументирована. Не нравится ни так ни этак,
>   выписывайте родовое наименование к видовому: в произведении "В лесах".
>
> ---
>
> Да не надо из «вконтакте» получать никакой такой формы. Оно уже в
>   нужной форме!

[ВКонтакте? В контакте? Во ВКонтакте?](http://grumbling-translator.blogspot.ru/2015/03/blog-post.html)

> ...Когда я пишу ВКонтакте в предложном падеже, я обычно не дублирую во
>   В. При щепетильной грамматической правильности этот вариант несколько
>   рябит в глазах. Я пишу: «Зарегистрироваться ВКонтакте». Ничего
>   страшного, что в данном случае предлог в пишется слитно с Контактом. В
>   конце концов, это осознанный маркетинговый ход данной компании. Да,
>   этот вариант не безупречен, но дублирование во В тоже далеко от
>   идеала.

Comment: Галина, там словосочетание "в чём-то и чём-то", поэтому даже лучше не повторять предлог. Например, "в Фейсбуке и Твиттере" звучит лучше, чем "в Фейсбуке и ***в*** Твиттере". Вот если их поменять местами и "ВКонтакте" поставить на первое место, тогда другое дело.

Comment: Артём, неповторяющиеся предлоги обязательно указывают. Типо в лесах и на горах.

Comment: Так я ведь как раз про повторяющиеся, что крупными буквами у Вас (про сети)!

Comment: Тёма, не вижу! То, что я нарисовала под верхней картинкой вопреки написанному на картинке, это такая моя ирония. 8-(

Answer (score 0):

Все понятно про упрощения и про удобство произношения, но мне интересно, как на это смотрят лингвисты. Я пока не могу принять беспредложный вариант в предложном падеже, не могу согласиться. Если бы пришлось публиковать «общаться (в/во) "ВКонтакте"» в литературном произведении или научной публицистике, как бы в этом случае было бы оформлено сочетание? Мне интересно именно правило, регулирующее подобные случаи. Есть ли такое? Специалисты на "Грамоте" советуют избегать стыка предлогов и использовать родовое понятие. Вероятно, нет пока фиксированной нормы, но и беспредложное управление (назовем это так) тоже не приветствуется, с чем я лично согласна. =(